# How to read (downloaded / result) filename from job

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

In a Pentaho 9.1 Job, using the "Get File(s) from SFTP" step, I download a CSV file.  I would like to use that downloaded file name in the subject line of the email message in the "Mail" step.

I have tried calling it as a variable but it is not really a variable but a "results" value.  Eample if what I tried below...

Downloaded file name = "somefile.csv"

Syntax in the "Mail" step for "Subject" = "File Processing Complete: ${short_filename}"

When email sends the subject is exactly "File Processing Complete: ${short_filename}" when I need it to be "File Processing Complete: somefile.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get file information from result. But unfortunately this step available only in the transformation. Thus, we need to get help a transformation to read the file name. I have prepared a **[SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cCxGV0VGiIsBzK10Bbf5ufabQ7L8LLu9?usp=sharing)** for you. You need to give right information for SFTP & MAIL configuration. Also please run job "getFromSFTP".

1. [getFromSFTP.kjb] Here, I download the csv file from sftp and send file information to transformation
2. [getFileName.ktr] Here, read the file information and send filename to another job for mail sending.
3. [sendMail.kjb] This job only use for send the mail with filename = ${filename1}

[image]

Comment: This was the exact solution I needed.  Much appreciated.